# Did I find a bug in Cygwin GCC (v 4.5.3)?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, cygwin

Within the following block of code, `num_insts` is re-assigned to `0` following the first iteration of the loop.

```
inst_t buf[5] = {0};
num_insts = 10;
int i = 5;
for( ; i > 0; i-- )
{
   buf[i] = buf[i-1];
}
buf[0] = next;
```

I cannot think of any possible valid reason for this behavior, but I'm also sleep deprived so a second opinion would be appreciated.

The assembly being executed for the buf shift is this:

```
004017ed:   mov 0x90(%esp),%eax
004017f4:   lea -0x1(%eax),%ecx
004017f7:   mov 0x90(%esp),%edx
004017fe:   mov %edx,%eax
00401800:   shl $0x2,%eax
00401803:   add %edx,%eax
00401805:   shl $0x2,%eax
00401808:   lea 0xa0(%esp),%edi
0040180f:   lea (%edi,%eax,1),%eax
00401812:   lea -0x7c(%eax),%edx
00401815:   mov %ecx,%eax
00401817:   shl $0x2,%eax
0040181a:   add %ecx,%eax
0040181c:   shl $0x2,%eax
0040181f:   lea 0xa0(%esp),%ecx
```

And the register contents prior to executing the first assembly instruction above is this:

```
eax 0
ecx 0
edx 0
ebx 2665332
esp 0x28ab50
ebp 0x28ac08
esi 0
edi 2665432
eip 0x4017ed <main+1593>
```

Following those instructions, this:

```
eax 0
ecx 0
edx 2665432
ebx 2665332
esp 0x28ab50
ebp 0x28ac08
esi 0
edi 2665456
eip 0x401848 <main+1684>
```

I don't know nearly enough assembly to make sense of any of this, but maybe someone answering this will benefit from it.

Comment: Since the code has undefined behaviour, any kind of investigation is pointless.

Comment: Check [this post](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/767) to see what craziness may happen when you use undefined behavior.

Comment: Examining the assembly code, as you now know, was not helpful. Running the code under a debugger or adding `printf` calls might have been.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For first iteration with `i = 5` you code:

```
for( ; i > 0; i-- ) // i = 5 > 0 = true
{
   buf[i] = buf[i-1];  // b[5] = b [5 - 1] 
}
```

Is `buf[5] = buf[4];`   because `buf` is just of size `5`,  maximum index value can be `4` so bug in your code = array out of index problem => rhs `buf[5]`.

Comment: I'm going to crawl in a hole now. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan No problem, it happen I saw at-least you putted efforts to bug your code yourself, that is the way of learning. Good Luck!